# Onenote page hierarchy

Tags: onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-api

Let's say I have a notebooks with name 'MyNotebook'. Now this notebook have a section group 'Group1' and now 'Group1' have another section group 'Group2'. Now inside 'Group2' I have section 'Section1' which has a page 'Page1'.

If we look this at like a directory structure the path to page will be -**MyNotebook/Group1/Group2/Section1/Page1**

When I try to get page using get page api I am able to get only immediate parent i.e Section1. So let's say I want get this complete hierarchy how I can get that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What API specifically are you using to get pages?

If you are using GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages, this will give you all the pages, though that API has limitations (For example, it is paginated, so it will only give you the most recent 20 pages. In addition, it won't work if the user has a big number of sections).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2017/07/21/a-few-performance-tips-for-using-the-onenote-api/

See the section "When getting all pages for a user, do so for each section separately"

I recommend you make a call like:

GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/Notebooks?$expand=sections,sectionGroups($expand=sections,sectionGroups($levels=max;$expand=sections))

To obtain all the sections, and then make a call like:

GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/{id}/pages

To obtain each section's pages.

Comment: I am using MS Graph api for Onenote to get pages. 
Let's say I have 3000 pages in my onenote account I can call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages api with skip and top parameter untill I get all the pages. Will that work without throttling ?

Comment: It should, yes. However, I don't recommend doing that. Call each section separately - it is much more performant.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jorge said, if you specifically want the upwards hierarchy (and not downwards), you could do:

GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?$expand=parentSection($expand=parentSectionGroup($expand=parentSectionGroup($expand=parentNotebook)))

But as Jorge said, be careful when using the GET pages API since it has some limitations